# How to calculate the number of n-dimensional Hadamard Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

This question may do some matter in finding chips for CDMA encryption,or cracking it's encryption.

The question can be expressed mathematically by following:

> How many n-dimensional vector sets containing $n$ vectors with elements of $-1$ and $1$, orthogonal to each other pairwise, are there?

when $n=4$, a sample vector set can be this:

$\{ (1,1,1,1),(-1,-1,1,1),(1,-1,1,-1),(1,-1,-1,1) \}$

---

Assume that we have a required vector set,let's put it into a matrix $H$:

$\{ \alpha_1, \alpha _2, \alpha _3, \cdots, \alpha _n \} = H$

It's easy to recognize that $H$ is a

Hamadard Matrix.

Obviously, this question is homogeneous to the question of counting n-dimensional [Hadamard Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix), whose answer is $n!$ times to the question above.

Firstly, **the required vector set only exist when $n$ is even.**

I have tried to calculate the answer-table by computer(C language, precisely), using Deep First Searching to enumerate all the sets(equally, all the Hadamard Matrix), and I get the following answer:

| n | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 8 | 122880 |

(I only make the table to $n=8$, the unlisted items' answer are $0$)

My solving process is blocked here.

It's obvious that the rising speed is unbelievable. So would there be a formula to solve this question? Or there can only be some optimized algorithms to calculate it?

Comment: See [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007299), where they only consider inequivalent ones. For a formula, see [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJoNjt_u6EAxXV9bsIHSqVDIgQFnoECDYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.e-periodica.ch%2Fcntmng%3Fpid%3Dens-001%253A1994%253A40%253A%253A67&usg=AOvVaw3K1CVP4LzlQ44_swxFxyqq&opi=89978449).